# Why I am not getting the same frequency when sampling a waveform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I am trying to simulate the sampling of a waveform to then apply FFT Analysis to it. Here is the sample code I have now using a square wave:

```
frequency =50;
sampleFrec = 1000;
period =1/frequency;

f=\[Piecewise]  -1  (period/2)<=Mod[x,period]<period
                 1  True                

testData=Table[N@f,{x,0,2*period,1/sampleFrec}];

Plot[f,{x,0,2*period}, PlotLabel->"Fundamental",ExclusionsStyle->Dashed, PlotStyle->{Thickness[0.006], Red}]

ListLinePlot[testData,PlotRange->Full, PlotLabel->"Fundamental"]
```

And this are the plots I'm getting, the first one is the 50Hz square wave I want but when I use `Table[]` and `ListLinePlot[]` I am not getting the same frequency, why? I am relatively new to Wolfram Mathematica so maybe this is something very stupid. Thank you for your help!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello Andres.  In this case you merely need to add `DataRange -> {0, 2*period}` to `ListPlot`.

Comment: Nice! Why this happens? The same doesn't happen with `Plot[]`

Comment: `ListLinePlot` has no way of knowing what range your data is supposed to cover, so it simply uses the number of data points as the range.

Comment: I closed this question because I felt it would be of limited use to future readers, and because I think the subject has already been covered on this site though I cannot find a good "duplicate" as the moment.  (Don't misunderstand: this is not the same as saying it is a bad question.)  I'll continue looking for a good duplicate.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I picked a Question to mark as the original.  Here also are related Questions: [(7940)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7940), [(40062)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40062), [(43845)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43845)